# wicket 9: error while trying to login using firefox

Tags: wicket

I have a simple login page

An excerpt

```
Button button = new Button("SignIn");
        AjaxEventBehavior onClick =
                new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(form, "click") {
                    @Override
                    protected void onAfterSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        Login login = form.getModelObject();
                        boolean authResult = AuthenticatedWebSession.get()
                                .signIn(login.getUsername(),
                                        login.getPassword());
                        //if authentication succeeds redirect user to the requested page
                        if (authResult) {
                            continueToOriginalDestination();
                        } else {
                            onError(target);
                        }
                        //authentication successful, but no destination page
                        //was found, so redirect to a home page
                        setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        System.out.println("test");
                    }
                };
```

The situation is that when I try to login everything works fine as expected - I get redirected
either to a page where I came from or to a home page. However, it seems that this solution does not work while trying to log in from Mozilla Firefox browser.

**The Situation**

when I log in via Firefox I get redirected to a page saying

```
Access Denied

You do not have access to the page you requested.

Return to home page
```

and url becomes: `https://localhost:8089/LogInPage.html?0-1.-form`, however if I hit refresh button after access denied page shows up then I get redirected as expected.

**What I've tried?**

replacing `onAfterSubmit` to `onSubmit`.

Clearing my cache.

Disabling CSP.

**My questions**

Am I missing something obvious?

Why this happens only in Mozilla Firefox?

How to fix it?

Comment: Does it work when you use a button to submit the form  instead of an ajax event?

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, it does not work